# Create UI to Semi-Automate Hosted Network Setup with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, adhoc

I have some batch code for a UI for reconfiguring and/or starting a hosted network. I'm having trouble debugging it. The if statement doesn't work. Please see below:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Provide user interface.
REM     Ask user if he would like to:

REM         1. Re-Configure hosted network
REM             i.  Collect data for hosted Network.
REM             ii. Provide status message letting user know if setup was successful.

REM         2. Start Hosted Network
REM             i.  Provide Status message (Success or Failure).

REM         3. Use timer to close application after completion.
:Begin

CLS
COLOR 0A

ECHO Please select one of the following options:
ECHO    1. Re-Configure your hosted network.
ECHO    2. Start your hosted network.
ECHO    3. EXIT
ECHO.

SET /P choice=Choice: 

IF "%choice%" EQU 1
    (
        GOTO :config
    )
ELSE IF "%choice%" == 2
    (
        GOTO :startUp
    )
ELSE IF "%choice%" == 3
    (
        GOTO :exit
    )
ELSE
    (
        CLS
        COLOR 4E

        ECHO INVALID SELECTION. PLEASE TRY AGAIN.

        TIMEOUT /t 5
        GOTO :Begin
    )

:config
ECHO Please enter the following information:
SET /P sSID=SSID/Network Name: 
SET /P key=Network Password : 
SET /P start = Start Network (Y/N)?

NETSH wlan SET hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="%sSID%" key="%key%" | FIND "        *successfully*"
NETSH wlan SHOW hostednetwork

IF /I "%start%"=="Y" GOTO :startUP

GOTO :exit

:startUp
NETSH wlan START hostednetwork | FIND "The hosted network started."
GOTO :exit

:exit
ECHO Exiting
FOR /L %Counter IN (0,1,9) DO
    (
        TIMEOUT /t 1000
        ECHO .
    )

pause
```

Please note I am using windows 8.1.

Also if someone would add the code to give the file admin privileges and show me how to pipe from the find statements into an IF statement that displays an error message if things fail I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The If command fails first because parentheses wrong. Also, you had quotes around the variable but not around the value. Finally, in GOTO don't use **:** before label.

Some set commands would have put spaces into the variables, which could cause failure when the variables were used. Removed the spaces. Be careful about extra spaces in general (no echo .), and especially in SET commands.

I added method for evaluating result of the find command. It counts lines containing the string and if result=0 the string was not found--Failure. There are various ways to run the file with admin privileges, but not using code within the batch.

```
@echo off
    REM Provide user interface.
    REM     Ask user if he would like to:

    REM         1. Re-Configure hosted network
    REM             i.  Collect data for hosted Network.
    REM             ii. Provide status message letting user know if setup was successful.

    REM         2. Start Hosted Network
    REM             i.  Provide Status message (Success or Failure).

    REM         3. Use timer to close application after completion.
:Begin
    CLS
    COLOR 0A
            ECHO Please select one of the following options:
            ECHO    1. Re-Configure your hosted network.
            ECHO    2. Start your hosted network.
            ECHO    3. EXIT
            ECHO.
        SET /P choice=Choice: 
            IF %choice% EQU 1 (
                GOTO config
            ) ELSE (
                IF %choice% EQU 2 (
                GOTO startUp
            ) ELSE (
                IF %choice% EQU 3 (
                GOTO exit
            ) ELSE (
                CLS
                COLOR 4E
                ECHO INVALID SELECTION. PLEASE TRY AGAIN.
                TIMEOUT /t 5
                GOTO Begin
            )))

:config
        ECHO Please enter the following information:
        SET /P "sSID=SSID/Network Name:" 
        SET /P "key=Network Password:" 
        SET /P "start=Start Network (Y/N)?"
        :: Confirm user typed y or n
            If /i not %start%==y echo.>nul &&If /i not %start%==n echo You didn't type y or n &&goto config
        REM NOTE: WILL USER EVER TYPE "N"? If yes, you know they get back here per goto at end (endless loop)

        rem Set var only because length of command
        Set NETSHwlan=NETSH wlan SET hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="%sSID%" key="%key%"
            For /f %%I in ('%NETSHwlan%^| FIND "*successfully*" /c') do (
                If %%I GTR 0 (
                    echo Success
                ) else (
                    echo Failure
                )
            )

        NETSH wlan SHOW hostednetwork
        IF /I "%start%"=="Y" GOTO startUP 
        GOTO config

:startUp
    For /f %%I in ('NETSH wlan START hostednetwork^| FIND "The hosted network started." /c') do (
            If %%I GTR 0 (
                echo Success
            ) else (
                echo Failure
            )
    )
    GOTO exit

:exit
    ECHO Exiting
        FOR /L %Counter IN (0,1,9) DO (
            TIMEOUT /t 1000
            ECHO.
            )
    pause
    exit
```

See REM NOTE in :config about endless loop

I don't think your counter will work. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. A search will turn up some effective methods.